# ToolBar ControlTemplates, Missing Overflow Items, and ToolBarTray Orientation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates, controls

I'm writing a ControlTemplate for toolbars that utilizes a UniformGrid in order to provide multiple columns for toolbar items. So far, it seems that even with mostly default ControlTemplate markup (a la [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970772(v=vs.110).aspx)), Overflow into the ToolBarOverflowPanel no longer works. I have tried using both the default ToolBarOverflowPanel **and** a StackPanel, to no effect; the relevant template snippit can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/BMAacCbd).

How do I get Overflow to work properly?

<strike>Additionally, when placing a ToolBar control inside a ToolBarTray, how can I detect and set the "Thumb", "Content", and "Overflow Toggle Button" to their correct positions? The documentation for ToolBar ControlTemplates does not seem to cover this.</strike>

**edit**: *Also something I'm curious about, how can I tie into the UniformGrid's Column property in my Main window xaml?*

**edit 2**: *Got the basic for dealing with ToolBarTray Orientation resolved, just needed to add ControlTemplate triggers for the related attached properties (Trigger Property="ToolBarTray.Orientation" Value="Vertical"). Also, who downvotes a decently written question, seriously?*

```
<ToggleButton DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
    ClickMode="Press"
    IsChecked="{Binding 
        IsOverflowOpen, 
        Mode=TwoWay, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}
    }" 
    IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding HasOverflowItems}" 
>
    <ToggleButton.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Border x:Name="Border"
                Background="{StaticResource 
                    {x:Static SystemColors.MenuBarBrushKey}
                }" 
                CornerRadius="0,3,3,0" 
                SnapsToDevicePixels="true" 
            >
                <Grid>
                    <Path x:Name="Arrow" 
                        Data="M -0.5 3 L 5.5 3 L 2.5 6 Z" 
                        Fill="{StaticResource {x:Static 
                            SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey
                        }}" 
                        Margin="2,3" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                    />
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ToggleButton.Template>
    <Popup x:Name="OverflowPopup" 
        AllowsTransparency="true" 
        Focusable="false" 
        IsOpen="{Binding 
            IsOverflowOpen, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}
        }" 
        Placement="Bottom" 
        PopupAnimation="Slide" 
        StaysOpen="false" 
    >
        <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder"
            Background="{StaticResource 
                {x:Static SystemColors.MenuBarBrushKey}
            }" 
            BorderBrush="{StaticResource 
                {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}
            }" 
            BorderThickness="1"
        >
            <StackPanel x:Name="PART_ToolBarOverflowPanel" 
                Focusable="true" 
                FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" 
                KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle" 
                KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" 
                Margin="2" 
            />
            <!--<ToolBarOverflowPanel 
                x:Name="PART_ToolBarOverflowPanel" 
                Focusable="true" 
                FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" 
                KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle" 
                KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" 
                Margin="2" 
                WrapWidth="200" 
            />-->
        </Border>
    </Popup>
</ToggleButton>
```